# Using AWS S3 Object Lifecycle, how can I remove deleted objects

Tags: amazon-s3

Is there a way I can use s3's object lifecycle to prune through current versioned objects and delete those objects premantely that have a deleted marker on them in lets say a month or a week?  If there isn't, how is house cleaning performed on versioned buckets?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) describes object lifecycle management generically.  [This page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/intro-lifecycle-rules.html) describes lifecycle configuration more specifically.

You cannot do precisely what you want with S3's built-in lifecycle.  With the versioning feature, there are two types of objects: the current version, and old non-current versions.  The current version is the latest, most recently uploaded version of your object.  For now, if the latest thing you've done to an object is cover it with a delete-marker, treat the delete-marker as the current version.

With S3's lifecycle, you can set up a rule to permanently delete non-current versions after X days.  (You can also set up rules to move to glacier after X days.)  But it sounds like what you're asking is for a rule where you can permanently delete non-current-but-only-if-the-current-is-a-delete-marker.  This isn't natively supported.

If you want to only delete objects whose current version is a delete marker, you'll have to write your own listing agent to walk your bucket, enumerate these objects, and delete them yourself.  There might be existing tools for this already; I haven't checked.

Comment: ok thanks thats what i thought I just wanted to make sure lol.

Answer (score 1):

Yes lifecycle configuration can be set  on a bucket `programmatically`simply by using  `Amazon S3 API` or in `console Amazon S3`.

Normally there are some lag before an updated  or may be new  lifecycle configuration ispropagated to  `Amazon S3` systems. There may be few minutes delay beforeit  fully takes effect.

and on disabling or deleting a lifecycle rule, after a small delay **Amazon S3** stops scheduling new objects for deletion or transition. Any objects that were already scheduled will be unscheduled and will not be deleted or transitioned.

**Deletion**

- Create a non-versioned delete request
- Specify a versioned delete request

Two out comes are possible:

- If the `version ID` maps to a specific object version, then `Amazon S3` deletes the specific version of the object.
- If the `version ID` maps to delete marker of that specific object, `Amazon S3` deletes the delete marker.means that object appear again in bucket.

check it http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingObjects.html